# How to set custom debug token when using Android App Check

Tags: android, firebase, store, firebase-app-check

I need to enter custom `debug token` to get my Android app running on Firebase Test Lab.

I generate debug token from the console.

How can I setup a provider factory with that `debug token`? I can't found a valid `class` to initiate. With `Web App Check`, we can enter the `token` directly.